# Change the style of only onPressed item of FlatList

Tags: react-native

I've been trying to change the color of the selected(onPress) item of the Flatlist but it's changing the color of whole list. I've added the code below:

```
class SelectionForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            textColor: '#333'
        };
    }

    typeSelected(value) {
        Alert.alert(value);
        this.setState({
            textColor: 'green'
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={[
                        { utId: '1', utName: 'Guest' },
                        { utId: '2', utName: 'Faculty' },
                        { utId: '3', utName: 'Student' }
                    ]}
                    renderItem={
                        ({ item }) => 
                        <Text 
                            style={[
                                styles.userListText, 
                                { 
                                    backgroundColor: this.state.bgColor, 
                                    color: this.state.textColor 
                            }]} 
                            onPress={() => this.typeSelected(item.utId)}
                        >
                            {item.utName}
                        </Text>
                    }
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({      
    userListText: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#333',
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#eee'

    }
});

export default SelectionForm;
```

I'm using Text to display the list. onPress the Text from the list, I'm getting the value of the clicked item but the style is changing for all list items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make your code depend upon the `id` of item for which you want to change the color.

Your state should have a identifier to track currently pressed item say `itemPressed` which should be initialized with an arbitary value say `-1` so that it doesnt signifies any item in the list.

so your `typeSelected` should look like this:

```
typeSelected(value) {
   Alert.alert(value);
   this.setState({
       itemPressed: value
   });
}
```

and your `Text` component should look like :

```
<Text 
   style={[
      styles.userListText, 
      { 
          backgroundColor: this.state.bgColor, 
          color: this.state.itemPressed  === item.utId ? 'green' : 'black'
      }]} 
      onPress={() => this.typeSelected(item.utId)}
>
```