# How to change color of specific item in FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native

const [itemsPressed, setItemsPressed] = useState(true);
const changeColor = (x) => {
setItemsPressed(x)
}

Answer (score 0):

If your `item` has some unique identifying ID/name, you can use that to help you track which one is pressed. (You could also just store the full item itself and do object equality but just a simple id/string is more than enough)

```
const [pressedItemIds, setPressedItems] = useState({});

const changeColor = useCallback((item) => {
  setPressedItemIds({...pressedItemIds, [item.id]: true});
}, []);

<FlatList data={data}
 renderItem={({ item }) => (
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => changeColor(item)}>
   <View
     style={backgroundColor: pressedItemIds.hasOwnProperty(item.id) ? '#8b0000': '#ffc6c4'}>
     <Text>{data.text}</Text>
     </View>
     </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
 )} />
```

Comment: What should useItem(null) be?

Comment: Apologies, meant to type useState!

Comment: I did that and pressedItem?.id never matches item.id and when I press nothing happens. When I console.log(data.id) I get undefined, but when I console.log(data[3].id) I get the desired id. I don't know how to fix this. My data array is
const data = [ 
{ english: 'Swimming', id: 1 }, 
{ english: 'Basketball', id: 2 }, 
{ english: 'Running', id: 3 },
{ english: 'Shopping', id: 4 }, 
];
and the code is the same as the one you shared

Comment: You need modify the code based on your appropriate data structure.

Also you shouldn't be using `data.id`. Your `data` is an array. In the code, 1 `item` represents an element in `data`. You should be using `item.id`. Please adjust the code based on your data structure or share a codesandbox showing your current problem that can be demoed and edited.

Comment: const [pressedItem, setPressedItem] = useState(null);

  const changeColor = useCallback((item) => {
    setPressedItem(item.id);
  }, []);
`<FlatGrid data={interesi}
    style={tw``}
    spacing={10}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={tw``} onPress={() => changeColor(item)}>
      <View style={[{backgroundColor: pressedItem?.id === item.id ? '#8b0000': '#ffc6c4'}, tw`flex justify-center items-center ml-2 -mt-1 rounded-2xl`]}>

Comment: `      <Text style={tw`text-black`}>{bulgarian && item.bulgarian2}{!bulgarian && item.english}</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )} />`

Comment: Please share code blocks in your original post, they don't parse as blocks here.

Comment: Don't edit this post if you have further clarifications - edit your own question

Comment: I accidently did, sorrry

Comment: I edited the original

Comment: The code looks good to me - which part is not working and what's the issue now?

Comment: When I press on any of the Views, the color doesn't change. A press is being registered, but the backgroundcolor doesn't change. I suspect it's because the pressedItem.id doesn't match the item.id. And I might need to verify pressedItem[index].id === item[index].id. Does it work for you?

Comment: The problem is likely your style values being incorrect. The code looks right to me as far as setting it goes. 1 item = 1 object with an id field and an english field. In the `changeColor` function, add a `console.log(item.id)` to confirm that you are in fact getting the ids on press.

Comment: I am getting the corresponding ids, but colors still don't change. I don't see how my style values are being incorrect though and can't quite figure out why they aren't changing.

Comment: It seems that pressedItem.id always stays undefined?

Comment: Can you paste your whole component code altogether

Comment: posted it as an answer

Comment: I found this solution, but if one is selected, the other one deselects:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616736/change-the-style-of-only-onpressed-item-of-flatlist
How do I not allow it to deselect, unless pressed again and allow to press multiple?

Comment: Ah quick point george - I just realized we're storing `item.id` in `pressedItem` so `pressedItem` IS the id. So in your style section, you want to do `pressedItem === item.id` not `pressedItem?.id === item.id`, because `pressedItem` itself is the id.

Comment: As for being able to handle multiple presses, you can utilize state to store a map of which ones are pressed and not pressed. I'll update my answer shortly

Comment: Please see my updated answer for how to store multiple presses

Comment: Can you please check the answer I just posted? Thanks!

Comment: Your answer does not handle multiple presses - I had updated my answer as i mentioned last time